# What is this pipe? I noticed water damage on my baseboard so I took it apart and found this but I’m not sure what needs to be done

Tags: water-damage, baseboard

So I’ve noticed water damage at the baseboards for a couple months now and decided to rip it apart and check behind. This is what I found but I’m not sure what I’m looking at and what needs to be done, there is also a pool of water below the pipe under the rubber substance surrounding the pipe.

This is on the first floor in the laundry room but on the opposite side of the washing machine.

Thanks for looking.

[image]

Comment: That looks like your main drain stack. If it is, then there tend to be lots of sanitary tees joining onto it from the sides, where all of the drain pipes in your home run downhill to reach these sanitary tees. Water could be running down any of these tributary drain lines above your opening here, then continuing down the stack. I would expect the water to grab onto some wall framing before it reached the bottom, though. The stack pokes through your roof and tends to have a "boot" around it to keep out rain water. On the roof is the first place I would look for the water source.

Comment: But this could also be a toilet drain.

Comment: Did someone manage to nail right through the protective plate into the pipe? The two black marks on the pipe and one thing that might be a hole in the protective plate matching that are suggestive. Or was the plate shorter than the baseboard and a nail went above it? Or there's a nailhole down low, hiding in the crud, as the rusty side is the bottom of the plate?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the washing machine (clothes washer, yes?) is directly on the other side of the pipe, from where the picture was taken? If so, this could be the clothes washer standpipe drain. Typically (at least in the US) there is a larger than normal vertical pipe (either inside of the wall, or sometimes outside of the wall) into which the clothes washer drain hose empties. This gives water-holding capacity while the large volume of water drains down.

Comment: The black mark on the pipe is just a mark and wasn’t caused by a nail. As far as having to go on the roof, I have an HOA so I’d have to see how that can be done. Also yes the pipe is directly across from my clothes washing machine.

Comment: @Anthony, he was asking if the pipe was behind the washing machine. The idea is that the washing machine and pipe were on "opposite" sides of the sheet of drywall that you removed. I've been assuming that the washing machine is across the room from this bad spot on your wall.

Comment: In hindsight it occurs to me that if that were the washer standpipe, there would be a trap there...

Comment: @Anthony there shouldn't be anything the HOA can say about you getting on your own roof for a few minutes for home maintenance. Then again, HOAs seem to think they have god-like powers. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your house from the outside so that you can see the roof above this pipe, can you see a pipe above this spot on the roof? If so, then this pipe is a plumbing vent. Your water problem is probably due to failed flashing on the roof around this plumbing vent. If you're comfortable getting up on the roof, then you can confirm by looking at the vent pipe from above and verifying that there exists a water infiltration point. If you're not comfortable getting up on the roof, then you should call a roofer to come confirm the problem and replace the flashing.

Comment: I likely will have to get someone to look at the roof, but besides checking the roof, is there anything I should do here besides replacing the protective plate, drywall and baseboard? Is the pool of water below the pipe normal?

Comment: No, the pool of water below the pipe is not normal.  You have a leak somewhere.

Comment: @Anthony, can you see the pipe poking through the roof from the ground at least? If there's no roof penetration, then you can move on to other explanations. I wouldn't replace the drywall and baseboard until you've found the water source and mitigated the problem.

Comment: It’s dark outside right now so I can’t see the roof, but I’ll check tomorrow. It’s a 2 story townhome and across from me the building is identical so if I can’t see mine I should be able to see theirs to confirm